# Block ads in YouTube video in android

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

I have added YouTube player in android project. While playing any video I'm getting so many  ads after some times.Is there any way to remove it by programming.

Comment: the reason why you can play videos "that are not yours" inside your applications is because they're funded with those ads. Obviously, you can't just play for free whatever you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had authorization from the content owners of the videos to upload copies in your own account, and then ensure that your account was set up with monetization turned off, then that would prevent ads from showing during playback. It's up to you to work out that arrangement/permission with the original videos' owners, of course.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot remove the ads that play at the beginning of the video .